# How to do XPath or XML parsing in Android

Tags: android, xml, xpath, lucene

I have string variable which contains XML of the form:

```
<item>
    <descriptin>abc</descripton>
    <title>def</title>
</item>
```

I want to the display the title *text* in a listview but I'm getting XML when I use:

```
String s=hitdoc.get("text")
```

I'm working with Lucene search in android if that helps.

Comment: I think the OP means the variable `s` now contains the XML.  "but I'm getting XML when I use" suggests that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to the display the title *text*

**You need to evaluate an XPath expression like**:

```
/item/title/text()
```

this selects any text node (in your case just a single one) that is a child of a `title` that is a child of the top element named `item`

**Or, to get the string directly, evaluate this XPath expression**:

```
string(/item/title)
```