# Android XML XPath error

Tags: android, xml, xpath

I have searched the internet quite a lot about this, but I am still struggling to get the following simple code working. Can anybody give me a hand?

The target platform is Android 2.2.

When evaluating, 1 node is returned, but the value is null - I would like the filename.

XML Reading code:

```
public String GetValue(String data, String xpath) {

    String value = "";

    XPath path = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    try {

        XPathExpression exp = path.compile(xpath);

        Document doc = this.GetDocument(data);
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList)exp.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        if(nodes.getLength() > 0) {

            value = nodes.item(0).getNodeValue();
        }
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return value;
}
```

Calling Code:

```
XMLHelper xhelp = new XMLHelper();
this.FileName = xhelp.GetValue(fileData, "tilesheet/filename");
```

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tilesheet>
    <filename>sheet.png</filename>
    <cellwidth>32</cellwidth>
    <cellheight>32</cellheight>
    <columns>9</columns>
    <cellcount>9</cellcount>
</tilesheet>
```

Thank you very much for your help,

Richard Hughes

Comment: Where do you actually specify an XPath expression?

Comment: In the calling code: tilesheet/filename

Comment: My mistake, I did not read carefully enough. I just checked the documentation, and the node value of an Element is defined to be `null`. I recommend using the `STRING` return type, and changing your XPath to be `tilesheet/filename[1]`

Comment: OK. Just looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366606/how-to-do-xpath-or-xml-parsing-in-android It seems this works: /tilesheet/filename/text()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Just looking at this: [How to do XPath or XML parsing in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366606/how-to-do-xpath-or-xml-parsing-in-android) It seems this works: /tilesheet/filename/text()